# Apache Server Config Set Headers Conditionally

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, configuration, cache, http-headers

I am trying to set cache age for 200 responses and no cache for rest of the calls.
I tried below config, which works fine when 200 OK response comes up and I can see max-age=800 in headers

But for other responses like 400 etc. I am not able to see cache-control header itself in developer console. Any clue to fix this issue. below is what i tried so far

```
   <If "%{REQUEST_STATUS} == '200'">
         Header set Cache-Control: "max-age=800"
    </If>
    <If "%{REQUEST_STATUS} != '200'">
         Header set Cache-Control: "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    </If>
```

Thanks,